# Fixing date type in a text file

Tags: c#

I am writing a text file with some data recorded inside a SQL database.

I am writing some data and one of them is a data, and it writes with this shape: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

How can I make it just writing `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Here is the code I am using to write the data in the text file:

```
if (sqlReader["TaxableGroupID"].Equals(1))
{ 
    tw.WriteLine(sqlReader["PartyFederalTaxID"] + ";" + sqlReader["TransSerial"] + sqlReader["TransDocNumber"] + ";" + sqlReader["CreateDate"] + ";" + sqlReader["TotalAmount"] + "\r\n" + sqlReader["BarCode"] + ";" + "23" + ";" + sqlReader["Quantity"]);
}
```

I have the same problem with the `TotalAmount`. I want to write it with a `.` to separate the decimals and it writes with a `,`. I have tested this code but didn’t work. The decimal separator still `,`.

```
if (sqlReader["TaxableGroupID"].Equals(1)) 
{
    tw.WriteLine(sqlReader["PartyFederalTaxID"] + ";" + sqlReader["TransSerial"] + sqlReader["TransDocNumber"] + ";" + sqlReader["CreateDate"] + ";" + sqlReader["TotalAmount".ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)] + "\r\n" + sqlReader["BarCode"] + ";" + "23" + ";" + sqlReader["Quantity"]); 
}
```

I tried this to fix the date problem but as the `.` problem, I didn’t get any error but the date stood the same.

```
if (sqlReader["TaxableGroupID"].Equals(1))
{
    tw.WriteLine(sqlReader["PartyFederalTaxID"] + ";" + sqlReader["TransSerial"] + sqlReader["TransDocNumber"] + ";" + sqlReader["CreateDate".toString("dd/MM/yyyy")] + ";" + sqlReader["TotalAmount".ToString] + "\r\n" + sqlReader["BarCode"] + ";" + "23" + ";" + sqlReader["Quantity"]);
}
```

Comment: *Your code* specifies the string's format. If it doesn't, *you* (the user's) locale is used to determine the format. The compiler probably already issues warnings that you are using localizable functions without specifying a culture

Comment: BTW *don't* concatenate strings like that, use the TextWriter methods that accept a format string, eg [WriteLine(string,object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60scc1f1(v=vs.110).aspx), add placeholders with the format specifiers and you want and the desired culture. By concatenating strings in this way, you generate a lot of temporary strings that just waste memory *and* you are unable to specify the format you want

Comment: I already posted a link to the version of WriteLine that accepts a format string. **ALL** TextWriter classes, String.Format and StringBuilder etc have overloads that accept a format string. So do many `ToString()` methods of built-in classes, eg `someDate.ToString("d")

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You can use Date property of DateTime object to get only the date.

Comment: @vortex how can I use that on my code ?

Comment: If the data is a string you can use for example DateTime.Parse to create DateTime object from given string and then use Date property -  DateTime.Parse(sqlReader["CreateDate"]). If it's DateTime already use sqlReader["CreateDate"].Date

Comment: @vortex I get an error "Cannot convert from "object" to "string" when I try to do what you have suggested

Comment: @Josue Figueiredo,give some example of decimal values

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM I have a number like 12,67 I want to make it 16.67

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM I need to replace the `comma (,) ` for a `dot(.) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this `Convert.ToDecimal(sqlReader["TotalAmount"]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
if (sqlReader["TaxableGroupID"].Equals(1))
 { 
    DateTime CreateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sqlReader["CreateDate"],  "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    tw.WriteLine(sqlReader["PartyFederalTaxID"] + ";" + sqlReader["TransSerial"] + sqlReader["TransDocNumber"] + ";" + CreateDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); + ";" + sqlReader["TotalAmount"] + "\r\n" + sqlReader["BarCode"] + ";" + "23" + ";" + sqlReader["Quantity"]);
 }
```

Note: **`sqlReader["CreateDate"]`** should be a string

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. And about my `dot` problem? You know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "12,67";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"));
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

[image]

Comment: @Josue Figueiredo,Try this one

Comment: It says I cant convert object to string

Comment: @Josue Figueiredo,It's Working for me,I also attach my output